# npm start giving a blank screen. Its not showing my app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, frontend, backend

Its giving me blank page on the home screen.How can I resolve it ? I want to render my frontend and want to see my website on the screen but its giving me "Cannot get/". My frontend it built in React.js how can I connect it with node.js and express to view it on the screen?

Here is my code-

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env' });

const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const SocketServer = require('./socketServer');
const corsOptions = {
  Credential: 'true',
  
};


const app = express();


    app.use(express.static("C:/Users/chirag/Downloads/mern-social-media-master/mern-social-media-master/" + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.sendfile("C:/Users/chirag/Downloads/mern-social-media-master/mern-social-media-master/" + "/public/index.html");
})

app.use(express.json())
app.options("*" , cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser())


//#region // !Socket
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);



io.on('connection', socket => {
    SocketServer(socket);
})

//#endregion

//#region // !Routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/authRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/userRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/postRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/commentRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/adminRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/notifyRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/messageRouter'));
//#endregion


const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useFindAndModify:false,
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Database Connected!!")
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening on ", port);
});
```

HTML code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src='C:\Users\chirag\Downloads\mern-social-media-master\mern-social-media-master\client\src\index.js'></script>
  <title>Web App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='C:\Users\chirag\Downloads\mern-social-media-master\mern-social-media-master\client\src\index.js'></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I've tried several ways but unable to resolve it. Is it due to cloudinary or mongoDB database?

I have added some code and modified several parts of it, but the error cannot be rectified.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`get/` denotes here about default end point which is of type `get` and contains only `/` in URL. Here in your code, all your endpoints starts with `/api` so you can add a new default endpoint/route like:

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
     res.send("Hello World")
})
```

It will display Hello World on you browser when you will navigate to home screen.

Comment: How can I redirect it to a file like my home page ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have any home route. Add a home route on top like bellow.

```
app.use('/', (req,res,next) => {
   return res.json('this is home route')
});
```

Comment: How can I redirect it to a file like my home page ?

Comment: that you can do on your frontend if express is just an api backend.

Comment: I'm unable to understand how? I've my frontend in react.js but I'm unable to connect it with it.

Comment: please share your frontend code and modify your question with both backend and frontend code and also describe what do you want to achieve and what errors you are getting if you have implemented the same.

Comment: I've edited it. Please read the question again and please try to help me with it.

Comment: you have not cleared your concepts on express. I suggest you do that first. this is just my guess on what exactly you are trying to do but this is not the way. please refer my new answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

create an index.html with the index.js file included in it and server that index.html for your home route. Do as follow in your backend

```
    // add following
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    
    // Remove Following
    app.get('C:\Users\chirag\Downloads\mern-social-media-master\mern-social-media-master\client\src\index.js',(req, res) => {
     res.send("C:\Users\chirag\Downloads\mern-social-media-master\mern-social-media-master\client\src\index.js")
})

// Add Following
app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})
```

Comment: Some blank page is popping up. Its not showing my frontend pages there.

Comment: have you created index.html with your index.js in your public dir ? if yes share your github repo if need more help

Comment: I've added the HTML code above and the updated express code also.